# Added properties not fully working after mongoose schema.add

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have 2 schemas. The first is from a module I've created and the second to extend said module.

A lot of things are working, but there is an issue.

```
const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    ean: {type: String, required: false, index: false},

    title: {type: String, required: true, index: false},
    description: {type: String, required: true},


    stock: {
        amount: {type: Number, required: true, default: 0},
        track: {type: Boolean, required: true, default: true},
    },

    relatedProducts: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'}],

    images: [{type: String, required: false}],

    live: {type: Boolean, required: true, default: false},
}, {
    minimize: false,
    strict: false,
    timestamps: {createdOn: 'createdOn', updatedOn: 'updatedOn'}
});
mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);

const ExtendedSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    preOrder: {
        isPreOrder: {type: Boolean, default: false},
        openFrom: {type: Date},
        openTill: {type: Date},
        releaseDate: {type: Date}
    },
});

ProductSchema.add(ExtendedSchema);
```

This works, but when I look up a document in the Product model that has the property `preOrder` set with value `{isPreOrder: false}` and I try to log it, the following shows:

```
{
    "stock": {
        "amount": 1,
        "track": true
    },
    "preOrder": {
        "isPreOrder": false
    },
    "relatedProducts": [],
    "images": [],
    "_id": "5c8c5d2c3e6bc4e97f8dbe30",
    "sku": "123456",
    "title": "Test product",
    "description": "Hi"
}
```

But when I try to access `product.preOrder.isPreOrder`, the following error is thrown: `Cannot read property 'isPreOrder' of undefined`.
BUT, `product.get('preOrder').isPreOrder` does work.

Can someone clarify this for me and maybe tell me how I can fix it so I don't need to call `.get` with every single property that might or might not be added later?

Comment: Could you show your query where you made console

Comment: The statement is as followed `const product = await Product.findOne({live: true, _id: req.params._id}).select(Wrapper.whitelist.get).populate('relatedProducts').exec();`
The console.logs are as followed: `console.log(JSON.stringify(product, null, 4))` and `console.log(product.preOrder.isPreOrder)`